# IBM Worklight SQL Adapter - Cannot connect to database. Cannot load JDBC driver class 'com.mysql.jdbc.Driver'

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, worklight-adapters

my adapter.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<wl:adapter name="DbConnect"

    <displayName>DbConnect</displayName>
    <description>DbConnect</description>
    <connectivity>
        <connectionPolicy xsi:type="sql:SQLConnectionPolicy">
            <!-- Example for using a JNDI data source, replace with actual data source name -->
            <!-- <dataSourceJNDIName>java:/data-source-jndi-name</dataSourceJNDIName> -->

            <!-- Example for using MySQL connector, do not forget to put the MySQL connector library in the project's lib folder -->
            <dataSourceDefinition>
                <driverClass>com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</driverClass>
                <url>jdbc:mysql://localhost:3036/test</url>
                <user>root</user>
                <password>root</password>
            </dataSourceDefinition>
        </connectionPolicy>
        <loadConstraints maxConcurrentConnectionsPerNode="5" />
    </connectivity>

    <!-- Replace this with appropriate procedures -->
    <procedure name="select"/>

</wl:adapter>
```

and adapter-impl.js

```
var statement = WL.Server.createSQLStatement("select * from categorie");
    function select(statement) {
        return WL.Server.invokeSQLStatement({
            preparedStatement : statement
        });
    }
```

**I downloaded the connector `.jar` driver and locate it in the `server/lib` folder**. I don't understand what could be wrong..

**edit:** below i post the message of console javascript when i run the app in worklight mobile browser simulator

```
wlclient init started wlgap.android.js:1481
before: app init onSuccess wlgap.android.js:1481
Request [/apps/services/api/Canti_Liturgici/android/query] wlgap.android.js:1481
after: app init onSuccess wlgap.android.js:1481
wlclient init success wlgap.android.js:1481
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 401 (Unauthorized) http://localhost:8080/apps/services/api/Canti_Liturgici/android/query
Request [/apps/services/api/Canti_Liturgici/android/query] wlgap.android.js:1481
response [/apps/services/api/Canti_Liturgici/android/query] success: /*-secure-
{"responseID":"8","errors":["Runtime: org.apache.commons.dbcp.SQLNestedException: Cannot load JDBC driver class 'com.mysql.jdbc.Driver'"],"isSuccessful":false,"warnings":[],"info":[]}*/ wlgap.android.js:1481
Procedure invocation error. Runtime: org.apache.commons.dbcp.SQLNestedException: Cannot load JDBC driver class 'com.mysql.jdbc.Driver' wlgap.android.js:1487
Failure {"status":200,"invocationContext":null,"errorCode":"PROCEDURE_ERROR","errorMsg":"Procedure invocation error. Runtime: org.apache.commons.dbcp.SQLNestedException: Cannot load JDBC driver class 'com.mysql.jdbc.Driver'","invocationResult":{"responseID":"8","errors":["Runtime: org.apache.commons.dbcp.SQLNestedException: Cannot load JDBC driver class 'com.mysql.jdbc.Driver'"],"isSuccessful":false,"warnings":[],"info":[]}}
```

Comment: Where did you find the connector? Which one did you download? Also - try to delete the .jar and put it back again, it helped me once.

Comment: @nute i solved the problem. I edited the port of url (is 3306 and not 3036), also i corrected the function `select(statement)` in `select()`

Comment: Can you please write this as an answer and mark it as Answered? Thanks.

Comment: @IdanAdar i have a question: if i want to run the application in a real device which is on the same lan of machine i must change the `<url>` value with the ip of the machine in lan or i have to do something else?

Comment: What you want to do is to open a new question with full details. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the problem. I edited the port of url in `.xml` file (is 3306 and not 3036), also i corrected the function `select(statement)` in `select()`.

below the two file corrected.

**adapter.xml**

```
<displayName>DbConnect</displayName>
    <description>DbConnect</description>
    <connectivity>
        <connectionPolicy xsi:type="sql:SQLConnectionPolicy">
            <!-- Example for using a JNDI data source, replace with actual data source name -->
            <!-- <dataSourceJNDIName>java:/data-source-jndi-name</dataSourceJNDIName> -->

            <!-- Example for using MySQL connector, do not forget to put the MySQL connector library in the project's lib folder -->
            <dataSourceDefinition>
                <driverClass>com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</driverClass>
                <url>jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test</url>
                <user>root</user>
                <password>mysql</password>
            </dataSourceDefinition>
        </connectionPolicy>
        <loadConstraints maxConcurrentConnectionsPerNode="5" />
    </connectivity>

    <!-- Replace this with appropriate procedures -->
    <procedure name="remoteDbSize"/>
```

**adapter-impl.js**

```
var statement = WL.Server.createSQLStatement("SELECT SUM( data_length + index_length ) FROM information_schema.TABLES WHERE table_schema =  \"test\" GROUP BY table_schema");
function remoteDbSize() {
    return WL.Server.invokeSQLStatement({
        preparedStatement : statement,
        parameters: []
    });
}
```